# Executar Ajax primeiro

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A última linha do código a baixo é a primeira a ser executada, e eu preciso que a função contendo esse ajax retorne true ou false, porém quando coloco para retornar dentro do success,error ou complete ele não funciona.

```
error: function (response) {
        if (((response.responseText.split("{")[1]).split("}")[0]).split(":")[1]) {
            confirmationValue = true;

        } else {
            confirmationValue = false;
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log(confirmationValue);
        return confirmationValue;
    }
});
console.log(confirmationValue);
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Ajax, como diz o próprio nome é assíncrono, logo dessa forma o return não fará sentido. Pode tentar usando async/await, exemplo [click aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506445/javascript-await-async-return-ajax-result)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o sync e await do ES6, desta forma você faz com que o restante do seu código aguarde o resultado da sua função ajax para continuar o código, no seu caso aguarda o retorno booleano para dar sequ

```
    async  function executar(){
    return $.ajax({
    'url': 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1',
    'metod': 'GET',
    success: async function(data){
        return data
    }
  })
}

async function chamaFuncao(){
  await executar()
  .then((res) =>{
        alert(res.name)
  })    

  alert('Continua a execução')

}

chamaFuncao();
```

Veja o exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vfapwm0/1/)